# Converting std::vector<std::string> to tuple class that is a child of vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, type-conversion

So I'm trying to make an illegal type conversion but it should be fairly easy to do it.

I have a `std::vector<std::string>` that I want to convert to a tuple.

My tuple class is this.

```
class Tupple: public std::vector<std::string> {
};
```

so they're pretty much the same thing, just with a different label. I'm wondering if I need to make some sort of copy constructor or something?

Thanks in advance.

---

Just to be explicit, if I can do this this I'll be a happy camper.

```
std::vector<std::string> contents = Token.description();
Tuple tup = contents;
```

Comment: Standard containers are not designed to be derived. Use encapsulation instead of inheritance. But to answer your question - yes, you need a copy constructor, or at least a `using` statement to expose access to the inherited constructors.

Comment: As @RemyLebeau was saying, you can achieve what you want by doing `using Tuple = std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @kanstar actually, I was thinking [more along this line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) instead: `class Tupple: public std::vector<std::string> { public: using std::vector<std::string>::vector; };`

Comment: @RemyLebeau what does the last `::vector` mean?

Comment: @financial_physician `std::vector<std::string>` is the class being derived from, the `::vector` after it refers to that class's actual constructor.  See the link I provided for more details.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks you guys!